# Creating multiple new columns of cumulative sums via loops

Tags: r

I have a data set with 50+ columns and I would like to create new columns for each with their cumulative sum. I am a beginner and have been handling these with individual lines, but would really like to learn how to do these using loops.

For example, initial data frame looks like this:

```
  A B C D E
1 1 2 4 7 4
2 0 1 3 9 5
3 1 3 2 3 1
4 0 0 4 2 1
5 1 1 5 1 1
```

and I would like something like this:

```
  A B C D E cA cB cC cD cE
1 1 2 4 7 4  1  2  4  7  4
2 0 1 3 9 5  1  3  7 16  9
3 1 3 2 3 1  2  6  9 19 10
4 0 0 4 2 1  2  6 13 21 11
5 1 1 5 1 1  3  7 18 22 12
```

Firstly, I would like to create new columns with a regular format as above.
Would I need two loops? One to create new columns and one to put values in those columns? I am aware that I can do this using `dplyr` but I am really wanting to learn how to use loops. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would require only one loop for each column. You can create new columns and assign values in the same loop

```
for (i in seq_len(ncol(df))) {
  df[paste0("c", names(df)[i])] <- cumsum(df[, i])
}

df
#  A B C D E cA cB cC cD cE
#1 1 2 4 7 4  1  2  4  7  4
#2 0 1 3 9 5  1  3  7 16  9
#3 1 3 2 3 1  2  6  9 19 10
#4 0 0 4 2 1  2  6 13 21 11
#5 1 1 5 1 1  3  7 18 22 12
```

---

Non `for` loop solutions could be

In base R

```
df[paste0("c", names(df)] <- lapply(df, cumsum)
```

Or just (as @markus mentioned)

```
df[paste0("c", names(df)] <- cumsum(df)
```

and using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(df, df %>% mutate_all(cumsum))
```

Comment: Thank you! For the for loop, I have this error: `Error in `[.data.frame`(allData6, , i) : undefined columns selected` 

And say I wanted to exclude the first column in the function as it's not numeric, how would I edit the code?

Comment: In the `for` loop we are selecting the column numbers for which we want to apply `cumsum`. For the given example, if you check output of `seq_len(ncol(df))` it gives you column number 1 to 5 which means we are doing `cumsum` over all columns. If you want to ignore first column one way would be to use `seq_len(ncol(df))[-1]` which will drop first element and the sequence would be 2 to 5. As far as the error message is concerned, are you applying `for` loop to the correct dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `tidyverse` without `bind_cols`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     mutate_all(list(c = ~ cumsum(.)))
#  A B C D E A_c B_c C_c D_c E_c
#1 1 2 4 7 4   1   2   4   7   4
#2 0 1 3 9 5   1   3   7  16   9
#3 1 3 2 3 1   2   6   9  19  10
#4 0 0 4 2 1   2   6  13  21  11
#5 1 1 5 1 1   3   7  18  22  12
```

---

Or using `colCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df1[paste0("c", names(df1))] <- colCumsums(as.matrix(df1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), B = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
1L), C = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), D = c(7L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L), E = c(4L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"))
```